# FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'XXXX' into field

Tags: python, django

This is a very strange error. I only receive it on my heroku server.

Here is how my model is:

```
# Abstract Model

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField('Enabled?', default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Country(CommonInfo):
    name = models.CharField('Country Name', db_index=True, max_length=200, help_text='e.g. France')
    official_name = models.CharField('Official Name', max_length=400, blank=True, help_text='e.g. French Republic')
    population = models.IntegerField('Population', help_text='Population must be entered as numbers with no commas or separators, e.g. 39456123', null=True, blank=True)
    alpha2 = models.CharField('ISO ALPHA-2 Code', max_length=2, blank=True)


class News(CommonInfo):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=250)
    slug = models.CharField('slug', max_length=255, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField('Body', null=True, blank=True)
    excerpt = models.TextField('Excerpt', null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

When I try to access News items from Admin site on my production server, I get this error (everything works fine on my dev server):

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'news' into field. Choices are: active, alpha2, date_created, date_updated, id, name, official_name, population
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 687, in _filter_or_exclude
     clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs)) 
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1271, in add_q
     can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1139, in add_filter
     process_extras=process_extras)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1337, in setup_joins
     "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
```

I run the same django (1.5.4) and python (2.7.2) versions on my production and development environments.

My production server is Heroku

Any ideas what could triggers the error?

**UPDATE**:

admin.py config is as follow:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from APP.models import Country, News


class NewsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News


class NewsAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    form = NewsForm

    search_fields = ['title', 
                     'country__name']
    list_filter = ('country',
                   'active'
                   )
    list_per_page = 30
    list_editable = ('active', )
    list_display = ('title', 
                    'active'
                    )
    list_select_related = True
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
```

Comment: So this happens when you access the admin? Can you post your admin.py file code?

Comment: Wherever I need to access the ManyToMany Relationship.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code that produces the error?

Comment: @jproffitt just updated the original question with my admin.py

Comment: Did you run migrations on the heroku server?

Comment: Yes. I just double checked. Tables in both environments are identical.

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is that why Django tries to find the name of the News table as a field in Country table?!

Comment: If you go with the default admin, do you have the same errors? My guess if your dbs look identical is that your admin.py is generating some error, and causing News to not be a recognized type for the admin, causing it to fallback to looking up news as a keyword for the Country model.

Comment: @foxwoods I'll check and let you know. Because the problem is on Heroku and not my dev environment, testing all of these scenarios is really cumbersome.

Comment: As long as you haven't tried plugging your dev environment to your Heroku database, you'll never be able to discard a database issue.

Comment: @btoueg Thanks for the advice. I connected my dev environment to Heroku database and everything worked flawlessly. I guess we can safely conclude that the issue is not related to the database.

Comment: @foxwoods Deleted everything from admin.py, with just the default admin, got the same error. The problem appears not to be related to admin.py. My next attempt is to rename the model and fields.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve the issue.

First, I managed to replicate the error in my local environment. At first, I was testing the application using built-in Django runserver. However, my production environment is Heroku that uses Gunicorn as webserver. When I switched to Gunicorn and foreman on my local server, I was able to replicate the error.

Second, I tried to pin point the issue by going through the models and add/remove different components, fields. To explain the process better, I have to add a missing piece to the original question.

The description I had posted above is kind of incomplete. I have another model in my models.py that I did not include in my original question, because I thought it was not relevant. Here is the complete model:

```
# Abstract Model   
class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField('Enabled?', default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Country(CommonInfo):
    name = models.CharField('Country Name', db_index=True, max_length=200, help_text='e.g. France')
    official_name = models.CharField('Official Name', max_length=400, blank=True, help_text='e.g. French Republic')
    population = models.IntegerField('Population', help_text='Population must be entered as numbers with no commas or separators, e.g. 39456123', null=True, blank=True)
    alpha2 = models.CharField('ISO ALPHA-2 Code', max_length=2, blank=True)

def get_country_names():
    names = Country.objects.only('name').filter(active=1)
    names = [(str(item), item) for item in names]    

    return names

class Person(CommonInfo):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=choices=get_country_names())

class News(CommonInfo):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=250)
    slug = models.CharField('slug', max_length=255, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField('Body', null=True, blank=True)
    excerpt = models.TextField('Excerpt', null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

My model design didn't require a ForeignKey for Person's table, so I had decided to go with a simple CharField and instead, use a regular drop down menu. However, for some reason, Gunicorn raises the above mentioned error when, as part of the get_country_names(), the Country table is called before News. As soon as I deleted the get_country_names() and turned the country field on Person table into a regular CharField the issue was resolved.

Reading through the comments in [this old Django bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1796) and [this post](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2010/04/30/django-manytomany-error-cannot-resolve-keyword-xxx-into-a-field.html) by Chase Seibert considerably helped me in this process.

Although ticket#1796 appears to be fixed more than 6 years ago, it seems that some tiny issues still remain deep buried there.

Thats it! Thanks everyone.

Comment: And that old Django bug helped me; the error was coming from a model in a library, and all I needed was to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` (oops...)

Comment: yes, was able to reproduce my issue running with gunicorn. Changing the model import order in admin.py fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to the possible situations under which this happens. I searched for the field that could not be found in any of my models.

Searching on the code I found that I was annotating a queryset with such field and then feeding that queryset as an `__in` search to another (along other complex queries).

My work around was to change that annotated queryset to return IDs and use that. On this particular case that result was always going to be small so the list of IDs was not a problem to pass.

Answer (score 3):

I'd had some ManyToMany relationships that were working one-way.  I had been messing around with my settings and changing the name of the main application a couple times.  Somewhere along the lines, I had removed it from the `INSTALLED_APPS` section!  Once I added that back in, then it worked.  Definitely PEBKAC, but maybe this will help someone some day.  It took me a while to think of checking for that, since the app was mostly working.

For example, my app is called `deathvalleydogs`.  I had two models:

```
class Trip(ModelBase):
    dogs = models.ManyToManyField(Dog, related_name="trips")

class Dog(ModelBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

when I tried to show a template for a `Trip` listing the `Dogs` that were on the trip like this:

```
{% for dog in trip.dogs.all %}
     <li><a href="/dogs/{{ dog.id }}">{{ dog.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

then I got an error of:

```
Cannot resolve keyword u'trips' into field. Choices are: active, birth_date, ...
```

Though I was still able to show a template for a `Dog` listing the trips they were on.  Notice that `trips` should have been a field created by the m2m on the `Dog` objects.  I wasn't referencing that field in the template, but it barfed on that field anyway in debug mode.

I wish the error had been more explicit, but I'm just so happy I finally found my mistake!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset migrations:

1. Remove the all migrations files within your project. 
   Go through each of your projects apps migration folder (**your_app/migrations/**) and remove everything inside, except the **init**.py file.
2. Run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong dunder lookup on an admin model search field, so for example:

Not working:

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "id",
        "thing_id",
        "count",
        "stuff_name",
        "stuff_id"
    )
    readonly_fields = ("count")
    # These cannot be resolved, because "stuff" doesn't exist on the model
    search_fields = ("stuff__name", "stuff__id")

    def stuff_name(self, obj):
        return obj.thing.stuff.name

    def stuff_id(self, obj):
        return obj.thing.stuff.id

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).select_related("thing")
```

Working:

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "id",
        "thing_id",
        "count",
        "stuff_name",
        "stuff_id"
    )
    readonly_fields = ("count")
    search_fields = ("thing__stuff__name", "thing__stuff__id", "thing__id")

    def stuff_name(self, obj):
        return obj.thing.stuff.name

    def stuff_id(self, obj):
        return obj.thing.stuff.id

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).select_related("thing")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error. And if your are using POSTMAN to do an API call to a URL, then you may be encountering this same error.

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'player' into field. Choices are ...

Either in your model or serializer, you are referring to a particular field e.g. `player` in my case as you would when it is referenced as a foreign key.

In my case I had a Player model, and I wanted to update the reference in the save method of a Market model, when a weight is changed in the market, it should reflect immediately on the player.

```
class Market(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    weight = models.CharField('Weight') 
    ...

    def save(self):
        if self.weight:
             # wrong
             Player.objects.get(player=self.player) # this object reference of itself does not exist, hence the error
             # right
             Player.objects.get(pk=self.player.pk)
             ...
        super().save()
```