# FieldError Cannot resolve keyword 'XXXX' into field, on wrong entity

Tags: django

I don't understand this error on my model. My model (django 1.5.4):

```
from django.db.models import Model
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ProductFactory(Model):

  name = models.CharField(_(u"Name"), max_length=128)
  products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='ProductFactoryProduct', related_name='factory')
  components = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='ProductFactoryComponent', related_name='factory')

class ProductFactoryProduct(Model):

  factory = models.ForeignKey('ProductFactory')
  product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
  quantity = models.IntegerField(_(u"Quantity"), default=1)

class ProductFactoryComponent(Model):

  factory = models.ForeignKey('ProductFactory')
  product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
  quantity = models.IntegerField(_(u"Quantity"), default=1)

class Product(Model):
  active = models.BooleanField(_(u"Active"), default=True)
  barcode = models.CharField(_(u"Barcode"), max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
  [...] # Nothing about factory
```

When i try to get Factory.products or Factory.components:

```
factory = ProductFactory.objects.get(pk=factory_id)
factory.products.all()
```

This error is throwed:

> FieldError at /stock/factory/view/1
>
> Cannot resolve keyword 'factory' into field. Choices are: active,
>   article, barcode, brand, categorys, code, comsumtion_type, id, name,
>   packaging, productreference, provider, providers, purchase_quantity,
>   quantity, quantity_with_ampute, stock_limit, stockmovement,
>   stockmovementproduct, work_unit

*Note*: active, article, barcode [...] fields are **Product** entity fields.

I don't understand why django is trying to use **factory** key on **Product** entity instead on **ProductFactoryProduct** entity. My model is wrong ? What is the problem ?

**Edit**: Full code: http://pastebin.com/SaMMUjd6

Comment: This error does not seem to have anything to do with either the query or the models you have posted. Please post the full traceback, the full relevant view, and the actual models.

Comment: Full code added on pastebin page.

Comment: In my case, I was importing two models with the same name and it returned the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In `class ProductFactory(Model):` `products` and `components` have the same `related_name` (`related_name='factory'`)

Try to change one.

Comment: Hi, same error but with updated related_name: "Cannot resolve keyword 'factory_product' into field. Choices are: active, article, barcode, [...]"

Comment: So remove `related_name`.

Comment: Same error, with a default related_name (choosed by django i assume): "Cannot resolve keyword 'productfactory' into field. Choices are: active, article, barcode, [...]"

Comment: On my django (1.7.1) everything works fine (with different `related_name`) Strange.

Comment: Maybe corrected bug when multiple ManyToMany on same Model ? It will be interresting to know in wich version of django it's corrected.

Comment: Maybe rekated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145787/fielderror-cannot-resolve-keyword-xxxx-into-field?rq=1 and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1796 . But i didn't understand these topics (english not my natural laguage)