# Getting cannot resolve keyword when using django filter

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm getting this error when I'm filtering csv output by date. And I also want to ask how to output a data to csv from last mont or past 6 months? as I only have `current_month & current_year` Thanks!

`Cannot resolve keyword 'created_at' into field. Choices are: amount, id, level, report, timestamp`

@models.py

```
class Rainfall(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default='')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

@views.py

```
def export_by_month(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    current_month = datetime.now()

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Level', 'Amount', 'Timestamp'])

    for i in Rainfall.objects.filter(created_at__month=current_month):
        writer.writerow(i)

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="rainfall.csv"'


def export_by_year(request):
    current_year = datetime.now().year
    return Rainfall.objects.filter(created_at__year=current_year)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'XXXX' into field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145787/fielderror-cannot-resolve-keyword-xxxx-into-field)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Rainfall` model does not have the attribute `created_at`. Maybe this is what you want:

```
Rainfall.objects.filter(timestamp__month=current_month)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks it works! :) but when I try to execute `export_by_year` I'm getting `too many values to unpack (expected 2)` error. what do you think I'm missing here?

Comment: Repeat what you did for `export_by_month` - your view functions need to return a response object, not a queryset